# HTML button not posting

Tags: html

I have a pretty simple html form with an embedded 'submit' button. Somehow it's just not posting.

Code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" formmethod="post" form="form1"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yep, URL which you post to is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form action="yourpage" method="POST" id="form1">`

Then the post should arrive on yourpage.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Late nights. Thanks